# Помогите разобраться как парсить xml

Tags: java, xml

есть xml файл

```
<tbl Data="2018-08-29">
<Table>
    <Book>
        <Name>ghjfjs</Name>
        <Price>Afddsdsgni</Price>
        <Size>25</Size>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>ghjfjs</Name>
        <Price>Afddsdsgni</Price>
    </Book>
</Table>
```

вот код:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(URL_PAGE);
NodeList cuntryElements = document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Book");
for (int i = 0; i < cuntryElements.getLength(); i++) {
  Node node = cuntryElements.item(i);
  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element element = (Element) node;
    ...
    String getCurrentElement = getTagValue("Size", element);
  }
}
```

все работает, вот только когда в xml нет элемента 25 в одном из блоков, то вылетает  NullPointerException.
Как можно проверить, что этот тег отсутствует?

Comment: getTagValue - ??

Comment: Где именно вылетает эксепшен?

Answer (score 2):

Вместо этого:

```
String getCurrentElement = getTagValue("Size", element);
```

Вы можете использовать следующий защитный подход:

```
String getCurrentElement = "";
if(element.getElementsByTagName("Size").getLength() > 0)
{
    Node nodeX = element.getElementsByTagName("Size").item(0);
    getCurrentElement = nodeX.getTextContent();
}
```

И использовать этот метод для всех элементов XML ...